# How do I put two conditions in having in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, having

I have to get members that are on five different groups and those groups should have 5 members each

- `Member` (idMember, nameMember)
- `Group` (idGroup)
- `Belongs` (idMember, idGroup)

Groups have members, members are in groups, a member can be in as many groups as he wants but a member can't be twice on the same group

I made something like

```
select idMember, nameMember
from Member m, Group g
where idMember in (select b.idMember
                   from Belongs b)
group by idMember, nameMember
having (select count(*) 
        from Belongs b
        where b.idMember = m.idMember)>5 
       and
       (select count (*)
        from Belongs b
        where b.idGroup = g.idGroup /*??*/)>5
```

and there I don't know how to relate belongs with group

Comment: Can you add some example data and expected output

Comment: yeah I was about to then I realized I had to make like a lot data and indenting it manually is a pain, is there an easier way of making it?

Comment: Never use commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: yeah but I don't know how to compare the group in belongs with the group itself, on top of that this messes up the result since I need to put group in "group by"

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approach this type of problem in steps.  The following gets the members that are in five groups:

```
select b.idMember
from belongs b  -- Note:  `group` is a reserved word so a bad name for a table
group by b.idMember
having count(*) = 5;
```

The following gets the groups that have five members:

```
select b.idGroup
from belongs b 
group by b.idGroup
having count(*) = 5;
```

(Interesting symmetry.)

If you want to limit the first query to the groups in the second, then a simple way is to use `in`:

```
select b.idMember
from belongs b
where b.groupId in (select g.idGroup
                    from belongs b
                    group by b.idGroup
                    having count(*) = 5
                   )
group by b.idMember
having count(*) = 5;
```

When you are dealing with complex queries, build them up one step at a time.

Note:  `group` is a really bad name for a table because it is a reserved word.  And, if you want the table name then use `JOIN` to join to the members table to get the right name.

EDIT:

You can use `join` to get columns from `member`:

```
select b.idMember, m.name
from belongs b join
     member m
     on b.idMember = m.idMember
where b.groupId in (select g.idGroup
                    from belongs b
                    group by b.idGroup
                    having count(*) = 5
                   )
group by b.idMember, m.name
having count(*) = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, It was simpler than I thought

Comment: I tried applying it but I can't seem to select columns from Member and doing what you posted here, can you help me?